# h2[class|=article-subtitle] {...} not worked

Tags: html, css

As i was practicing advanced attribute selectors, when i tried the first one it worked but when i tried the second one it didn't worked.

Why? What's the reason?

```css
 h2[class~=article-subtitle] {
  background: grey;  /* --> it worked */
}

h2[class|=article-subtitle] {
  background: white; /* --> not worked */
}
```

```html
<h2 class="subtitle article-subtitle">About Me</h2>
    
    <img src="../images/lessonimg-1.jpg">
    
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. 
    
    Cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla , pariatur:
    
      <ul>
        <li>Excepteur sint occaecat</li>
        <ol>
          <li>My numbered list item</li>
        </ol>
      </ul>
    </p>
```

Comment: I’m sorry to put it that way, and it doesn’t necessary concern your issue, but the HTML is a mess. Closing tags are missing, and you cannot put an <ol> as a child of <ul>, it should be inside an <li>.

Comment: Don't say sorry, i came here to gain knowledge and you are giving it, so there is nothing wrong in giving suggestions
When it comes to messy html, i'm practicing so we know well it will be messy & the 'ol' inside ul is to just to test the output as i was new to this. But thanks for saying something.

Comment: Even as an advanced web developer I strongly recommend to write code in a proper integrated development environment (IDE) like the free [Atom](https://atom.io/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), instead of a text editor. It allows catching errors of all levels, and sometimes even suggests better ways of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

> The `[attribute~="value"]` selector is used to select elements **with an attribute value containing a specified word**.

> The `[attribute|="value"]` selector is used to select elements with the specified attribute, **whose value can be exactly the specified value, or the specified value followed by a hyphen (`-`)**.

<sub>Quotes taken from [W3's CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).</sub>

---

The attribute you're trying to target is:

```css
class="subtitle article-subtitle"
```

So, the first one will work since `article-subtitle` is a single word contained in the `class`

However, since `article-subtitle` is not *exactly the specified value*, it won't match. It's missing the `subtitle` part of the class to be an exact match.

Comment: means, if i mention " h2[class|=subtitle article-subtitle] {...} ", will it work

Comment: Yes that should work if you quote the string: `h2[class|="subtitle article-subtitle"]`. But then it's not that much better than using a normal `=`

Comment: Ok, thank you, i have one more doubt regarding another attribute selector, can u please explain it for me

img[src="../images/lessonimg-1.jpg"] {
  color: 10px solid red;
}

i tried this as the below code doesn't work

img[src="../images/"] {
  border: 10px solid green;
}

but it still doesn't worked. Why?